# Raid , слетел Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, администрирование, hdd, диск, raid

Есть Windows XP SP3 с RAID.
Проверяли антивируской систему, начала винюснуть на скане одного файла,перегрузили ПК кнопкой удалили файл, заного запустили.
Теперь завис на другом файле, но после загрузки слетела Windows, пишет про файлы windows/system32/config
Как так получилось?
Из-за того что удалил данные начало восстанавливаться система и не вовремя перегрузил?
При вставке второго диска, одного, система завелась.

Comment: >при вставке второго диска система завелась

С этого места подробнее - зачем вынимали диск?

Comment: Ничего непонятно про вставку диска. Опишите подробнее дисковую конфигурацию и что с ней происходило. И какой RAID - он может быть программный, аппаратный и разных типов. А вообще я бы диски на ошибки потестировал.

Comment: Да принесли бэкапный диск, но решили попробовать сначало поменять местами диск, не получилось, потом второй диск вставить вместо первого,а первый высунуть и 
Операционка завелась.
Интересно,есил вставить отформатированный RAID подыментся?

Comment: Как узнать,какой RAID?

Comment: Вынимал, так как не мог загрузится, начал писать отсутствуют файkы в windows/system32/config.На диске изьял логи системы, думаю антивируска зависла на скане файла и в этот момент шло зеркалирование дисков, физически перегрузили и этим убили операционку

Comment: Получается для RAID  установленна программа Intel Matrix Storage Manager